# Symmetric matrix from the quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices

> Find the symmetric matrix $A$ for $$x_1^2+x_3^2+8x_1x_2-6x_1x_3+4x_2x_3, (x_1,x_2,x_3)∈\mathbb{R}^3$$

---

**My work so far**

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&4&-3\\4&0&2\\-3&2&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A-\lambda I=\begin{bmatrix}1-λ&4&-3\\4&0-λ&2\\-3&2&1-λ\end{bmatrix}$$

$$λ^3+2λ^2+28λ-68$$

$$  \lambda_1 \approx -5.442, \qquad \lambda_2 \approx 2.559, \qquad  \lambda_3 \approx 4.882$$

Is my process correct so far? Also, if no $x_2^2$ value is provided, would $0$ go in its place?

Comment: The matrix $A$ is already symmetric. Do you need to diagonalize it?

Comment: @A.Γ. Thanks for the confirmation. Would the 0 be fine in $a_{22}$, if $x_2^2$ is missing from the quadratic form? I also worked out the diagonalising process to see if my process if correct so far, to understand the process better.

Comment: You can check by yourself if $A$ is correct: compute $\mathbf{x}_T A \mathbf{x}$ and discover if it coincides with the quadratic form you have started with

Comment: $x_2^2$ is "missing" means $...+0\cdot x_2^2+...$, i.e. $a_{22}=0$.

Comment: @FormulaWriter Thanks for that. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @A.Γ. Superb explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an illustration of Sylvester's law of Inertia. The relationship between my $H$ and $D$ is called "congruence." This says that there are two positive and one negative eigenvalue. Which you knew...

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 8 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 4 &  - 3 \\ 
4 & 0 & 2 \\ 
 - 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 4 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 16 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 17 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 8 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 16 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 17 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 4 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 4 &  - 3 \\ 
4 & 0 & 2 \\ 
 - 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$